# What are some applications of the Kronecker product of matrices?

Tags: matrices

I knew how to compute the Kronecker product of two matrices, and maybe use it as a convenient way to vectorize MATLAB code, but I never really understand this operation intuitively.

Can someone point me to some interesting application of Kronecker product, hopefully not on 0-1 matrices?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily found with a google search here

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/296185/

On a more personal note, quantum mechanics uses such products quite frequently.